# do-while loop only works when condition uses "and" not "or"

Tags: java, do-while, boolean-expression

I have a do-while loop using the following condition: `while(p!=0 && k!=0);`. The loop works fine when I use `&&` as the operator. However, for the purposes of the program, I need to use `||`. The loop runs once and then hangs without throwing any exceptions. Can anyone tell me why the do-while loop hangs? Full code with comments:

```
//Import necessary dependencies
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.math.plot.*;

public class fixedSimulation 
{
    //Initialize variables
    public static int pacifists, killers, deaths, survivals, csvIndex = 0;
    public static double[] csvProb = new double[121];
    public static int[] csvParamP = new int[121], csvParamK = new int[121];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //These "for" loops serve to run the simulation 100 times for every possible combination of 0-10 pacifists and 0-10 killers
        for(int p = 0; p<11; p++)
        {
            pacifists = p;
            for(int k = 0 ;k<11; k++)
            {
                killers = k;
                //Display the number of pacifists and killers in current group (100 trials) of simulations
                System.out.println("P" + p + "K" + k);
                deaths = 0; survivals = 0;
                for(int t=0; t<100; t++) 
                {
                    //Run simulation
                        doRun();
                    //Display current total of deaths and survivals for simulation group
                    System.out.println("\nDeaths=" + deaths + " Survivals=" + survivals);
                    //Display current probability for simulation group
                    System.out.println("Probability of survival = " + (((double)survivals/(double)(survivals+deaths))*100) + "%\n");
                }
                //Record data for later use
                csvProb[csvIndex] = (((double)survivals/(double)(survivals+deaths))*100);
                csvParamP[csvIndex] = p;
                csvParamK[csvIndex] = k;
                csvIndex++;
            }
        }
        //Display collected data in "Comma-separated value" format, for easy use in spreadsheet applications
        System.out.print("CSV Data:\nPacifists,Killers,Probability");
        for(int x = 0; x < 121; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("\n" + csvParamP[x] + "," + csvParamK[x] + "," + csvProb[x]);
        }
        //Prepare to display scatter plot
        System.out.println("\nPlotting");
        //Create arrays for plot data
        double[] plotX = new double[121], plotY = new double[121], plotZ = new double[121];
        //Populate arrays
        for(int x = 0; x < 121; x++)
        {
            plotX[x] = csvParamP[x];
            plotY[x] = csvParamK[x];
            plotZ[x] = csvProb[x];
        }
        //Initialize plotting panel
        Plot3DPanel plotPanel = new Plot3DPanel();
        plotPanel.addScatterPlot("Plot", plotX, plotY, plotZ);
        plotPanel.setAxisLabels("Pacifists", "Killers", "Probability of Survival");
        System.out.println("Plot Done, opening frame");
        //Create UI window
        JFrame plotFrame = new JFrame("Pacifists and Killers");
        plotFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        plotFrame.setSize(700, 700);
        plotFrame.setContentPane(plotPanel);
        plotFrame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Frame opened");
    }

    //Simulation method
    public static void doRun()
    {
        //Instantiate values for test
        int p=pacifists, k=killers; 
        //"do" loop simulates meeting, checks to see if there are still killers and pacifists to meet, and if so simulates subsequent meetings
        do
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            //Pick two numbers between 0 and 2; random result of 0 is pacifist, 1 is killer. 2 is used as upper limit because random limit is exclusive.
            int r1 = r.nextInt(2), r2 = r.nextInt(2);
            //Check to see if 2 pacifists have met (if first number [r1] is 0 and second number [r2] is 0)
            if( (r1==0 && r2==0) && (p>=2) /* Check to see if there are 2+ pacifists; must be 2+ pacifists for them to meet */ )
            {
                //Display meeting and result
                System.out.println("P&P: P=" + p + " K=" + k);
            }
            //Check to see if a pacifist and killer have met (if first number [r1] is 0 and second number [r2] is 1)
            else if( ((r1==0 && r2==1) || (r1==1 && r2==0)) && (p>=1 && k>=1) /* Check to see if there are 1+ pacifist(s) and 1+ killer(s); must be 1+ pacifist(s) and 1+ killer(s) for them to meet */) 
            {
                //Remove pacifist
                p--;
                //Display meeting and result
                System.out.println("P&K: P=" + p + " K=" + k);
            }
            //Check to see if 2 killers have met (if first number [r1] is 1 and second number [r2] is 1)
            else if( (r1==1 && r2==1) && (k>=2) /* Check to see if there are 2+ killers; Must be 2+ killers for them to meet */ )
            {
                //Remove 2 killers
                k-=2;
                //Display meeting and result
                System.out.println("K&K: P=" + p + " K=" + k);
            }
        }
        //Check to see that pacifists and killers still exist
    ------> while(p!=0 || k!=0); <------


        //Display and record final result
        if(k==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Traveler survives");
            survivals++;
        }
        else if(k!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Traveler dies");
            deaths++;
        }
        //Catch extraneous errors
        else System.out.println("ERROR: Unknown end");
    }
}
```

Comment: [How do you transform a `&&` expression into an equivalent `||` expression?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: p!=0 && k!=0 is equal to !(p==0 || k==0)

Comment: In the future, please post a [short, self contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/). We don't need all that unnecessary code that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using `while(p!=0 || k!=0);` because I realized **after** writing the program that it needed to do something else.

@ZongZhengLi Sorry, I have no idea what is causing the problem, so I figured having all the code would help.

Comment: The process of reducing the code will often make it obvious where the error is. The shorter code is also faster for other people to understand (and therefore to help you with). In addition to Zong Zheng Li's suggestion, you should generally show the code you're having trouble with (so here you'd use the `||` formulation), what the output/error is, and what expect or want it to be (if not obvious).

Comment: @telmer6, this is how the solution is derived. Let A be p!=0 and B be k!=0. You have A.B expression. You start with double NOT. So you get !!(A.B). This equals !( !A + !B ). So you end up with !( p==0 || k==0). This method also works when you want to convert OR to AND. The important thing to recognize is !(A.B) = !A + !B. !(A+B) = !A.!B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with using `while(p!=0 || k!=0)` (as described in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058895/do-while-loop-only-works-when-condition-uses-and-not-or#comment33448808_22058895)) with this code.

When `k` is one (which it **starts out as** in the first invokation of `doRun`), you have created an infinite loop since you require that `k >= 2` to enter the block where it's decremented:

```
else if( (r1==1 && r2==1) && (k>=2) /* Check to see if there are 2+ killers; Must be 2+ killers for them to meet */ )
{
    //Remove 2 killers
    k-=2;
    //Display meeting and result
    System.out.println("K&K: P=" + p + " K=" + k);
}
```

Hence `k` will never be decreased and `p!=0 || k!=0` will always be true.

There are ways to fix that problem which will reveal a related one. If `k` starts out odd, it can never be zero. It will jump from `1` to `-1`, but you are checking for inequality with `0` instead of using `>`.

On a more fundamental level, why do you want to run the loop until both `p` and `k` are zero? Seems like the wrong thing to do in your scenario.

Completely separately, there's no need to continually create a new `Random` object inside the loop. Create it once and then call `nextInt` repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll move the random object and take a look at the other points!

Answer (score 1):

To correct the previous comment by @anonymous

```
 p!=0 && k!=0 is equal to !(p == 0 || k == 0)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  Oh, wait ... it is!

Comment: @DavidWallace Why is it not an answer?

Comment: @DavidWallace I was just thinking the same thing.  Please educate me.

Comment: Maybe for the benefit of OP. Show how it is derived.

Comment: I've re-read the question.  There isn't actually a question in it.  So it's impossible to answer.  So I've removed my downvote from here and applied one to the question instead.  This answer is probably about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

So, a few notes.

As others have commented and answered, DeMorgan's law shows the proper way to convert a logic statement from using AND to using OR. Just replacing AND with OR will cause no end of problems, as you discovered. In the future I'd recommend using a debugger (perhaps in Eclipse?) to step through your logic and see exactly how it's resolving.

More generally, though, there's no magic to logic statements like this. The easiest way to prove that DeMorgan's works is to set up a logic table:

```
             | Expression 1   ||                              | Expression 2    
 p!=0 | k!=0 | (p!=0 && k!=0) || p==0 | k==0 | (p==0 || k==0) | !(p==0 || k==0) 
------+------+----------------++------+------+----------------+-----------------
 true | true | true           ||false |false | false          | true            
 true |false | false          ||false | true | true           | false           
false | true | false          || true |false | true           | false           
false |false | false          || true | true | true           | false
```

These sorts of tables are easy to draw, and I hope easy to follow. You can see how the "Expression 1" on the left is equivalent to the "Expression 2" on the right. If your logic gets more complex, the table can get large, but this kind of careful derivation will prevent most common mistakes.